# Copying deprecated module into newer version of Magento (1.7)

Tags: magento-1.7, module

We have the find feed working in an older version of Magento (1.5).

I copied `app/code/community/Find` to our 1.7 installation.

I also copied `app/etc/modules/Find_Feed.xml`

The database table has been created.

After refreshing the Magento cache and re-logging into the Admin, "TheFind Feed" appears just where it is supposed to, under Catalog. It's sub-menu items "Manage Attributes" and "Manage Items" also appear there. But when I click on either of them, the result is a "blank" admin page.

Does anyone know why the admin interface for the module is not showing up?

**EDIT:**

I have gotten closer to solving this with programmer_rkt's help.

I completely forgot to copy the app/design/adminhtml/default/find folder. After that, and refreshing the Magento cache again, the admin interface showed up. But the feed file did not seem to save. I realized that some config settings saved in the database table `core_config_data` were missing. Here they are:

```
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                                      | value       |
|           | default |        0 | advanced/modules_disable_output/Find_Feed | 0           |
|           | default |        0 | feed/settings/findfeed_filename           | thefind.txt |
|           | default |        0 | feed/settings/findfeed_update             | 0           |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

"thefind.txt" will, I believe, appear in the magento var/export/find_feed/ folder, although I may have added some custom code to achieve that. I'm not sure if that is the default.

The export still is not working for me on the new system, but at least the admin controls are visible now.

Answer (score 1):

Question is too broad to answer. However I have a strong feeling that, **you forgot to include layout update xml file of the module with magento 1.7**.

So find out which layout xml file is using by this module in admin section. You can find out the xml file name from `config.xml` file  (if any) and include it in `adminhtml/default` theme (this is the default `package/theme` of admin section)

Please note, you may need to include the template files that are specified inside layout xml file (if any).

If nothing is working for you, then update your question with adding every single file of the module that you talking about. We are happy to help you.

Comment: I was originally going to title the question "Copying TheFind Feed module into newer version of Magento" but I thought that broadening the topic might make the answer useful to more people.

Comment: any luck on finding layout xml file ?

Comment: Actually, I think it was the fact that I didn't copy over any of the adminhtml template files! The admin controls are now visible.

Comment: yep. If my answer helped to resolve the issue then feel free to accept it. So that future visitors will also get benefit from your question. If you feel my answer is inadequate, then feel free to answer  your own question and put a tick on it :-)